# Security for Rails-based javascript apps: How do you verify permissions on a user within rendered javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security, backbone.js, coffeescript

Apologize if this is the wrong stack for this question. If so, please direct me to the correct site.

I have a rails app, where-in users can be a member of one of three roles: `user`, `admin`, or `system`.  My rails app basically serves as a JSON backend for a backbone app, however.  All the client-side heavy lifting is done via coffeescript files, which are handled in the asset pipeline.

Right now, I'm piping some user attributes into the javascript, via an object I create in at the `application.html.slim` level.  Something that looks like this:

```
APP.currentUser = 
  name: "#{@current_user.name}"
  role: "#{@current_user.role}"
```

Sprinkled throughout a few places in my backbone apps are calls like this:

```
if APP.currentUser.role is 'admin'...
```

This seems very insecure, since anyone with the knowledge could open up a dev console, modify the instance of `App.currentUser` to be `admin`, and then access the admin functionality of the front end.  Now, the rails side is smart enough to check and make sure that `@current_user` can execute those functions before it attempts to do so, but it still seems like there should be a way to prevent that on the front end, without publishing the role into the javascript.

Am I being overly cautious, or missing something?

Comment: You're being overly cautious. It doesn't matter at all if the user can enable "admin" stuff client-side, so long as the server doesn't let it do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can do better than this. I used to do something like this in cases where I need to introduce action permissions on my views. Something like this:

### At the Rails back-end:

```
def as_json(options={})
    super(:include => {
        :attributes_to_include
    }
    ).merge({
        :permissions=> {
            :can_create => (user.can_create?),
            :can_delete => (user.can_delete?),
            :can_update => (user.can_update?)
        }
    })
end
```

### At the Backbone front-end

```
if(@user.permissions.can_create)
    # Display create view
if(@user.permissions.can_update)
    # Display update view
.....
```

Generally that's the best you can do. You can not hide the view from the user in the front-end unless the entire page is loaded from the Rails back-end with view permissions taken care of. And of course contradicts with how Ajax-based views are handled nowadays.

Also, you need to make sure you authorize actions on the Rails back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're missing anything, but I don't think there is any way to have your cake (the admin and non-admin UI residing in a single backbone app) and eat it too (make the admin UI securely inaccessible to non-admins). You basically have to choose between only downloading the admin UI to confirmed admins and living with this "opening".